# VBA COPY PASTE SKIP -BEGINNER

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried but can not figure it out on my own what I am trying to accomplish:

In col-A on sheet-1 there  is a header row `<numbers>` followed by the numbers 1-12 this populates A1:A13.

What I would need is for a copy paste skip VBA code to loop through column A on sheet-1 and paste the first 4 cells (numbers: 1,2,3,4) in sheet2 Column B starting at sheet-2 B6 then copy the next 4 cells from sheet-1 (numbers:5,6,7,8)and copy it to sheet-2 column B 5 rows down to the end of the last populated row from sheet-1 column A (as there may be some in the dataset) .

```vb
  Sub CopySkipRws()
       Dim i As Long, r As Long
       Dim Rng As Range
    
       With Sheets("Sheet1")
          Set Rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
       End With
       For i = 6 To Rng.Count * 9 Step 9
      
          r = r + 1
          Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = Rng(r).Value
       Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: I had come across the following which worked for individual lines:                             Sub CopySkipRws()
       Dim i As Long, r As Long
       Dim Rng As Range
    
       With Sheets("Sheet1")
          Set Rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
       End With
       For i = 6 To Rng.Count * 9 Step 9
      
          r = r + 1
          Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = Rng(r).Value
       Next i
    End Sub

Comment: @ChantalMacream Can you edit your original question and add that code, properly formatted, to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take the basic idea from the below code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, Lastrow1 As Long, Lastrow2 As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook
    
        Set w1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set w2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
        
    End With
    
    With w1
    
        Lastrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 1 To Lastrow1 Step 4
        
            .Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + 3).Copy
            
            If i = 1 Then
                w2.Range("B6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Else
                Lastrow2 = w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                w2.Range("B" & Lastrow2 + 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        
        Next i
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    End With       
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If I want the intervals to be every 250 rows would I adjust this line: 'w2.Range("B" & Lastrow2 + 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues' and change the 5 to 250

Comment: So this solution above works when the column is blank, however I am looking for a solution that copies every 5th row regardless of if the rows in between are blank.

Comment: Please update your question and import some data in order to understand the new request